# ノードのグルーピング

Tags: html, xml, vb.net, linq

VBによるnodeのグルーピングがしたいのですが、初心者故行き詰っています．ご教示をお願いいたします．

［入力ファイル］
次のような変則的なHTMLです．bodyの下位は要素で構成されているのではなく`<BR>¶`（¶は改行コード）を単位に区切られています．

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE></TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<U>【書類名】　　　　　　　手続補正書</U><BR>
<SUP>【提出日】</SUP>　　　　　　　平成２０年１月２１日<BR>
<SUB>【あて先】</SUB>　　　　　　　特許庁長官　殿<BR>
<FONT SIZE="6">【事件の表示】</FONT><BR>
<FONT SIZE="5">　　【<U>出願番号</U>】　　　　<?pi 処理命令 ?><!--コメント-->特願<SUP>２０１７</SUP>－<SUB>５０６７２０</SUB></FONT><BR>
【補正をする者】<BR>
...
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

この`body`タグの下位ノードを、終末の改行でグルーピングしたいのです．

［作成したプログラム］

今できているコードは以下で、このあと`body`配下の`nodes`をどうグルーピングしたらよいかわからなくなっています．

```
    Dim streamReader As StreamReader = New StreamReader("D:\My_Documents\XML2019\JPO-HTML\testdata\F58737H1-mod.html", Encoding.GetEncoding("Shift_JIS"))
    Dim SgmlReader As Sgml.SgmlReader = New Sgml.SgmlReader()
    SgmlReader.DocType = "HTML"
    SgmlReader.WhitespaceHandling = Xml.WhitespaceHandling.All
    SgmlReader.CaseFolding = Sgml.CaseFolding.ToUpper
    SgmlReader.InputStream = streamReader
    Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(SgmlReader)
    Dim body As XElement = doc.Element("HTML").Element("BODY")
    Dim nodes As IEnumerable(Of XNode) = body.Nodes
```

このようなグルーピングは「自分の前の改行の個数を取得する関数」を作って、それをLINQ + XMLのGroupByに組み込むので良いと思うのですが、その肝心な点がわかりません．

以上 よろしくお願いいたします

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己RESです．解決しました．
まず前提条件がよくありませんでした．

> 終末の改行でグルーピングしたいのです．

XMLとして読んだ場合、行の先頭が要素ならvbCrLfは単独で出現しますが、例の`【補正をする者】<BR>`のようにテキストで行頭が始まる場合、`vbCRLf + 【補正をする者】`というような形でテキストノードが出現してしまします．（`vbCrLf`は、前の行の物）つまりテキストファイルとして読むならまだしも、XMLで読む限り、改行はグルーピングのキーとは成り得ません．

代わりに、行末の`<BR/>`をキーにしてグルーピングしてみました．以下はそのサンプルコードです．

```
Dim nodes As IEnumerable(Of XNode) = body.Nodes

' BODY以下のnodeをBR要素をキーにしてグルーピングする．
Dim groupedNodes =
    From node In nodes
    Group node By key = getBrCount(node)
    Into Group
' 特許庁HTMLのBODY以下の行の処理
For Each group In groupedNodes
    Dim lineNodes As List(Of XNode) = group.Group.ToList
    ' ここにグルーピングしたノード毎の処理を記述
Next

...

' <BR/>を数える関数
Function getBrCount(node As XNode) As Integer
    Return countBrElemNode(node, 0)
End Function

Function countBrElemNode(node As XNode, count As Integer) As Integer
    If node Is Nothing Then
        Return count
    ElseIf (node.NodeType = XmlNodeType.Element) AndAlso (CType(node, XElement).Name.LocalName = "BR") Then
        Return countBrElemNode(node.PreviousNode, count + 1)
    Else
        Return countBrElemNode(node.PreviousNode, count)
    End If
End Function
```

もし改善の余地などありましたらご教示ください．